# Empty Array of a Defined Length

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I am trying to create an Array of 100 elements where each of the elements is filled by a randomly generated integer.

```
        int[] NumArray1 = { };
        int[] NumArray2 = { };
        Random Ran = new Random();
        int ran1, ran2;
        for (int x = 0; x <= 99; ++x)
        {
            ran1 = Ran.Next(0, 10);
            NumArray1[x] = ran1;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y <= 99; ++y)
        {
            ran2 = Ran.Next(0, 10);
            NumArray2[y] = ran2;
        }
```

Except I want NumArray1 and NumArray2 to be 100 elements long.

Comment: `var intArray = new int[100]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
Random ran = new Random();
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    arr[x] = ran.Next(0, 10);
}
```